# Extreme execution time differences between local and production with same data in MySQL with innoDB

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, database-performance, alter-table

I'm trying to execute an `ALTER TABLE` to convert a table to UTF-8. I exported all the data from a very large table in production and imported it on my local mySQL instance to test how much time it would take and prepare myself.

The table contains 33 millions rows but it contains only 3 columns.

Here is the query for the conversion:

`ALTER TABLE image_public_key CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci, FORCE;`

When I run that query in my local instance running on a small laptop with a SSD, it is done in approximately 5 minutes. No big deal.

When I run the same query, in the same table in production using Amazon RDS with a `db.r3.xlarge` instance, it takes 55 minutes (which is 11x the time!).

I'm trying to understand how a small laptop can beat a machine like that (4cpu + 30 gb RAM + 800 Gb of memory total, 300 Gb free at the moment).

Could it be some throttling on Amazon side? Some default variables? Any help would be appreciated. I need to run the same query on multiple table and cannot put production on hold for so much time...

**EDIT**

I might add that the task stay stuck for a very long time with the state `copy to tmp`. Not sure if this is a useful information.

Comment: On AWS, the DB might be doing a backup before the `ALTER`?

Comment: @SamChats Not that I'm aware of but worth taking a look

Comment: question why would a `image_public_key ` need utf8 as COLLATE... using ascii as COLLATE would make more sense which uses less bytes bs utf8... less bytes also means more performance logical wise..

Comment: *" I need to run the same query on multiple table and cannot put production on hold for so much time..."*  Try to force the ALTER into using [Online DDL Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html) and add `ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;` then the table should still be usable during the ALTER for other clients.. If `ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;` is not allowed or possible then you will get a error..

Comment: *"I'm trying to understand how a small laptop can beat a machine like that (4cpu + 30 gb RAM + 800 Gb of memory total, 300 Gb free at the moment)."* Well it might be the case your MySQL configuration is nof optimal for the `db.r3.xlarge ` system or it can be simply a case of overselling that to many instances are running on the same system/ (nas) disks and the disks cant handle the IOPS required for all running queries?..  In both cases this answer is offtopic here consider contacting amazon? Or go to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ to get MySQL config help

Comment: What is the IOPs rating of your Amazon server?

Comment: @RickJames These volumes deliver single-digit millisecond latencies and the ability to burst to 3,000 IOPS for extended periods of time. Baseline performance for these volumes is determined by the volume's size.

Comment: And the volume's size is...?

Comment: @RickJames 630 gb